# Excepción producida en 0x78B208F0

Tags: c++

Estoy utilizando Visual Studio. El codigo compila pero cuando llega a la sentencia **int tam=strlen(cad);** Salta la excepcion producida 0x78B208F0. Es un programa que cambia todas las letras de una frase que introduzcas por mayusculas. No veo cual es el error.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char* cad = new char();

void main()
{
    
    printf(": ");
    scanf("%s", &cad);

    int tam = strlen(cad);
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        if (cad[i] < 123 && cad[i]>96)
        {
            cad[i] = cad[i] - 32;
        }
    }

    printf("\n%s\n", cad);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Una cadena es, por definición, un array de caracteres, es decir, una lista de elemntos de tipo `char`. Es por ello que debes usar `new[]` en vez de `new()`. `new()` hace una reserva que te permite almacenar un único elemnto de tipo `char`, el resto de caracteres de la cadena se almacenarán en posiciones de memoria que no pertenecen al array.

Dicho con código:

```
// Array con capacidad para 199 caracteres (más el finalizador de cadena)
char * cad = new char[200];
```

Claro que también puedes usar `std::string` para almacenar las cadenas y `cin` para leer de la entrada estándar, lo que te permitirá despreocuparte sobre la gestión de la memoria

```
std::string cad;
std::cin >> cad;
```

Por cierto, no hay necesidad de que `cad` sea una variable global. Intenta evitar el uso de variables globales ya que suelen ser muy problemáticas